# How to restore initial screen after GRUB

Tags: gnome, xfce

Actually i use Ubuntu `16.04` with `Gnome 3`, and decide to test a `xfce`.

So i purged `xfce` and the screen after GRUB always show `xubuntu` logo and login input is not from `gnome`

Comment: where plymouth themes removed? also may need to switch to GDM from LightDM.

Comment: Also purged `plymouth-themes-xubuntu-*` but the login input stay with `xfce` style